# SQL Query for Counting Distinct Values From One Column When More Than 1 Distinct Value exists in Another Column in the same table

Tags: sql

I have a single table called "Vehicle" that contains a column with unique VehicleId's. On this same "Vehicle" table I also have a column for QuoteId's.

I need to create a SQL query that returns how many distinct QuoteId's were obtained with more than one distinct VehicleId. In other words, I'm trying to determine a count of how many quotes had more than one vehicle on them.

I have searched all over for this information and come up with a basic text statement to try and help me figure this out:

"Select the count of distinct QuoteId's that have multiple distinct VehicleId's"

I am unable to come up with a way to get this to work but have included an example of what I am attempting to accomplish to try and clarify:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT QuoteId's) AS 'Multi Vehicle Quotes'
From Vehicle
WHERE VehicleId = DISTINCT VehicleId > 1
```

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @joanolo: But the solution is just basic Standard SQL, which runs on every DBMS, I doubt there's a better/worse performing solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are very close there. You need to first find quotes with more than one vehicle and store that in a CTE. Then count the number of quotes from the CTE.

```
With CTE as (
SELECT (
 VehicleID
 ,COUNT(DISTINCT Quotes)
FROM Vehicle
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Quotes) > 1)

SELECT COUNT(VehicleID) as MultiVehicleQuotes
FROM CTE
```

Answer (score 0):

You need nested aggregation:

```
select count(*)
from
 (
   SELECT QuoteId
   From Vehicle
   group by QuoteId
   having count(DISTINCT VehicleId) > 1
 ) as dt
```

Instead of `COUNT(DISTINCT) > 1` which is expensive you can also use

```
having min(VehicleId) <> max(VehicleId)
```

Comment: Is the having clause much faster?

Comment: DISTINCT is more complex than MAX/MIN. It might not be faster, but will probably use less CPU, simply test it on your system on a large table :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a query that will help you achieve what you want..

```
 SELECT DISTINCT vehicleId, qouteId,count(qouteId) as vehicleCountForQouteId FROM Vehicle GROUP BY qouteId
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume this is the data on your `vechicle` table:

```
SELECT * FROM vehicle ORDER BY vehicle_id ;
```

```
vehicle_id | quote_id
---------: | -------:
         1 |      100
         2 |      100
         3 |      100
         4 |      101
         5 |      102
         6 |      102
         7 |      103
```

Your **first step** would be to get the list of `quote_id`, and how many there are of each. Since, in the previous table, `vehicle_id` is unique, you just need:

```
SELECT
    quote_id, count(*) AS number_of_vehicles_quoted
FROM
    vehicle 
GROUP BY
    quote_id ;
```

```
quote_id | number_of_vehicles_quoted
-------: | ------------------------:
     100 |                         3
     101 |                         1
     102 |                         2
     103 |                         1
```

**Second step**: from the previous query, you want only those with `number_of_vehicles_quoted` > 1.
That can be done with a `HAVING` clause after the `GROUP BY`, which places a further restriction on the `GROUP`ed rows.

```
SELECT
    quote_id, 
    count(*) AS number_of_vehicles_quoted
FROM
    vehicle 
GROUP BY
    quote_id 
HAVING
    count(*) > 1 ;
```

```
quote_id | number_of_vehicles_quoted
-------: | ------------------------:
     100 |                         3
     102 |                         2
```

If you don't like `HAVING`, or don't feel comfortable with it, you can wrap the query with another one, and do:

```
SELECT
    quote_id, number_of_vehicles_quoted
FROM
    (SELECT
        quote_id, 
        count(*) AS number_of_vehicles_quoted
    FROM
        vehicle 
    GROUP BY
        quote_id 
    ) AS q
WHERE 
    number_of_vehicles_quoted > 1 ;
```

**Third step**: finally, count(*) the number of rows of the previous query:

```
SELECT
     count(*) AS count_of_quotes_with_more_than_one_vehicle_id
FROM
    (SELECT
        quote_id, 
        count(*) AS number_of_vehicles_quoted
    FROM
        vehicle 
    GROUP BY
        quote_id 
    HAVING
        count(*) > 1
    ) AS quotes_with_more_than_one_vehicle_id ;
```

```
| count_of_quotes_with_more_than_one_vehicle_id |
| --------------------------------------------: |
|                                             2 |
```

You can check the whole setup and the steps at *dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=f194ac724ed7c6e464fdce1cc330eb15)*. The query is plain SQL, and works with all engines available on DBFiddle (except Oracle, which complains about identifiers being too long, and that would work if I weren't so verbose ;-)

---

NOTE 1: you can simplify a bit the last query, since you don't use some of the information on the outermost query. That will speed it up a bit, although not in a significant way:

```
SELECT
    count(*) AS count_of_quotes_with_more_than_one_vehicle_id
FROM
    (SELECT
        -- quote_id,   -- You actually don't use this one in the outer query
        -- count(*) AS number_of_vehicles_quoted -- This neither
        1
    FROM
        vehicle 
    GROUP BY
        quote_id 
    HAVING
        count(*) > 1
    ) AS quotes_with_more_than_one_vehicle_id ;
```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=7d2edbe2c4c5c33e8a9fc4ea5af540fa)*

---

NOTE 2: If your `vehicle_id`s were not guaranteed to be unique, you'd use:

```
SELECT
    count(*) AS count_of_quotes_with_more_than_one_vehicle_id
FROM
    (SELECT
        1
    FROM
        vehicle 
    GROUP BY
        quote_id 
    HAVING
        count(DISTINCT vehicle_id) > 1
    ) AS quotes_with_more_than_one_vehicle_id ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, try this:

```
SELECT    COUNT(a.QuoteID)  AS 'Count', 
          a.QuoteID         AS 'QuoteID'
FROM      Problems.Vehicle  AS a
GROUP BY  a.QuoteID
HAVING    COUNT(a.QuoteID)  > 1
```

NOTE: Problems.Vehicle is the name of the schema the table is in and the name of the table.